# SQL select with not required where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I want to select some data from different tables with some primary and foreign key links.

The AppointmentID is not necessary but when there is no link betweeen RC.CMO and RC.Appointments_RC.CMO, the select give me a null result, cause the "where" is not satisfied.

How can I select all data, also when there is no appointment for the cmo?

I tink that is the problem:

```
AND
[RC.CMO].cmo_id = [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].cmo_id
AND
[RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].appointment_id = [RC.Appointments].appointment_id
```

I cant find some data if the person is not linked to an appointment.

Statement:

```
SELECT 
  [RC.CMO].ci_nummer
, [RC.CMO].raum
, [RC.CMO].anzahl_monitore as cmo_mon
, [RC.CMO].gebäude as gebaeude
, [RC.CMO].bemerkung
, [RC.Persons].kostenstelle
, [RC.Persons].vorname
, [RC.Persons].nachname
, [RC.FMO].hardware_typ
, [RC.FMO].anzahl_monitore as fmo_mon
, [RC.FMO].zubehör as zubehoer
, [RC.Appointments].appointment_id
FROM [RC.CMO]
   , [RC.Persons]
   , [RC.Persons_RC.CMO]
   , [RC.FMO]
   , [RC.Persons_RC.FMO]
   , [RC.Appointments]
   , [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO]
WHERE [RC.CMO].cmo_id = @cmo_id
AND   [RC.CMO].cmo_id = [RC.Persons_RC.CMO].cmo_id
AND   [RC.Persons_RC.CMO].person_id = [RC.Persons].person_id
AND   [RC.Persons].person_id = [RC.Persons_RC.FMO].person_id
AND   [RC.Persons_RC.FMO].fmo_id = [RC.FMO].fmo_id
AND   [RC.CMO].cmo_id = [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].cmo_id
AND   [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].appointment_id = [RC.Appointments].appointment_id
```

Is it possible to make an exists OR not exists?

Comment: try to create a left join

Comment: Use JOIN syntax. This is required to have a left join, and you should do it anyway because this mess is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. i removed duplicate tables and optimised the joins:

```
SELECT [RC.CMO].ci_nummer
     , [RC.CMO].raum
     , [RC.CMO].anzahl_monitore as cmo_mon
     , [RC.CMO].gebäude as gebaeude
     , [RC.CMO].bemerkung
     , [RC.Persons].kostenstelle
     , [RC.Persons].vorname
     , [RC.Persons].nachname
     , [RC.FMO].hardware_typ
     , [RC.FMO].anzahl_monitore as fmo_mon
     , [RC.FMO].zubehör as zubehoer
     , [RC.Appointments].appointment_id
  FROM [RC.CMO]
 inner join
       [RC.Persons_RC.CMO]
    on [RC.Persons_RC.CMO].cmo_id = [RC.CMO].cmo_id
 inner join
       [RC.Persons]
    on [RC.Persons_RC.CMO].person_id = [RC.Persons].person_id
 inner join
       [RC.FMO]
    on [RC.Persons_RC.FMO].fmo_id = [RC.FMO].fmo_id
  left join
       [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO]
    on [RC.CMO].cmo_id = [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].cmo_id
  left join
       [RC.Appointments]
    on [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].appointment_id = [RC.Appointments].appointment_id
 WHERE [RC.CMO].cmo_id = @cmo_id
```

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your query to use the modern explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the old-fashioned implict one, you can have `OUTER` joins, which do exactly what you want:

```
SELECT 
  [RC.CMO].ci_nummer
, [RC.CMO].raum
, [RC.CMO].anzahl_monitore as cmo_mon
, [RC.CMO].gebäude as gebaeude
, [RC.CMO].bemerkung
, [RC.Persons].kostenstelle
, [RC.Persons].vorname
, [RC.Persons].nachname
, [RC.FMO].hardware_typ
, [RC.FMO].anzahl_monitore as fmo_mon
, [RC.FMO].zubehör as zubehoer
, [RC.Appointments].appointment_id
FROM [RC.CMO] 
JOIN [RC.Persons] ON [RC.CMO].cmo_id = [RC.Persons_RC.CMO].cmo_id
JOIN [RC.Persons_RC.CMO] ON [RC.Persons_RC.CMO].person_id = [RC.Persons].person_id
JOIN [RC.FMO] ON [RC.Persons].person_id = [RC.Persons_RC.FMO].person_id
JOIN [RC.Persons_RC.FMO] ON [RC.Persons_RC.FMO].fmo_id = [RC.FMO].fmo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [RC.Appointments] ON [RC.CMO].cmo_id = [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].cmo_id
JOIN [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO] ON [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].appointment_id = [RC.Appointments].appointment_id
WHERE [RC.CMO].cmo_id = @cmo_id
```

Comment: Old timers also had OUTER JOINS using [`*=` and `=*`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx) ;-)

Comment: @StuartLC Was not aware of that syntax. Thanks!

Comment: I need to left join the link between [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO].appointment_id = [RC.Appointments].appointment_id and and it works!